# Vue / Nuxt SSR: Hydration text mismatch reports server with client values

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I currently have a [Pinia store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXzBy.png) in NuxtJS, which I use to show the [total items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T4BO.png) in the shopping cart. [Script setup shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Slk.png). The isLoggedIn getter is currently not implemented, so it always returns `false`.

Adding items to the cart works flawlessly and they are shown in local storage. However, when refreshing the page, the console shows [this warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/603Td.png).
I expected it to show up, since after all the server has no local storage, but what I did not expect is the server to report a value of `2`, instead of the client which for some reason shows `0`.

No middleware defined for the route, the script of the component only contains the store import and initialization at the top, and only vuetify as plugin registered.

How can this be?

Took a quick look at the [hydration](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/3127c4113e6ff381cd8f79a445655f759e08372a/packages/runtime-core/src/hydration.ts#L136) implementation, however I have found nothing.

Wrapping the v-btn with a  tag does make the warning disappear, but that doesn't really answer my question of why the server is reporting as if it was the client.

Debugged the application both on the server and the browser, and both had the expected values. (2 in the browser, and 0 on the server)

Tried with nuxt v3.5.3, v3.6.0 & v3.6.1, all had the same behavior.